# Darktable 3 does not have print option (Ubuntu 18.04 Snap install)

Tags: 18.04, printing, snap, darktable

I installed Darktable 3.0.1 in Ubuntu 18.04.4 via Software. It installs the Snap version.

But I can't find the print tab (Only visible are: lighttable, darkroom, other, map, slide show).

How to fix printing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The snap version appears to be missing some features, such as opencl support and printing. Try to remove the snap install and reinstall with *sudo apt* from the terminal.

3.0 version of darktable should be available from universe for 20.04, for older versions of Ubuntu, to install the latest 3.0 version add this ppa repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntuhandbook1/darktable
```

Install Darktable:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install darktable
```

Comment: Yes that worked, but that gives the older 2.4 version, not version 3.

Comment: ubuntu-focal-universe has version of darktable 3.0.1-0ubuntu1, check your software sources that universe is enabled. In vanilla Ubuntu gui, find and open app "Software & Updates", and under "Ubuntu software", is the box for (universe) ticked?

Comment: I think the universe has version 2.4.2 (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=darktable)

Comment: `apt show darktable` returns:

`Package: darktable
Version: 3.0.1-0ubuntu1
Priority: optional
Section: universe/graphics
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Debian PhotoTools Maintainers <pkg-phototools-devel@lists.alioth.debian.org>`

It seems to be v3, also I do not have ubuntuhandbook in my sources and I have version 3 (from universe). Make sure you have universe enabled, as it is an optional source, not necessarily switched on after a new install.

Comment: I just realized that you are on 18.04, I am using 20.04; there indeed seems to be an older version in universe for 18.04.